# Can't use dataweave syntax in VSCode

Tags: vscode-extensions, dataweave, anypoint-code-builder

In attempting to write a dataweave library in VSCode with DataWeave 2.0 (BETA) extension installed, I get errors with importing and using dataweave syntax.

Unable to resolve reference of: `firstWith`.DataWeave : Scope(InvalidReference)
I also have the same issue with keywords "then" and "$".

I've been unable to find similar problem by googling.

[Import Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IV8Du.png)

- tried importing firstWith from dw::core::Arrays and using other dataweave syntax
- expected no errors to show

Comment: Please **do not** post images of code, data, error messages, etc. Copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. Code or sample data in images can't be copied and pasted in order to search about a problem or reproduce it. For more details read the Meta FAQ entry [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557)

Answer (score 0):

May be a bug. You should not use that beta extension now that Anypoint Code Builder is released. Uninstall any MuleSoft/Anypoint extensions you installed individually and instead install the [Anypoint Extension Pack](https://docs.mulesoft.com/anypoint-code-builder/start-acb#install-pack). Note that having git installed in your system is a [prerequisite](https://docs.mulesoft.com/anypoint-code-builder/start-acb#before-you-begin-desktop-ide-setup).

Comment: The Anypoint Extension Pack doesn't seem to have the ability to run standalone dataweave scripts. Or at least I can't find any information or buttons for that.

Comment: You want to run standalone scripts, ie: outside a Mule application?

Comment: Not outside of a mule project, but I want to run them outside of a flow.

Comment: If the preview feature (https://docs.mulesoft.com/anypoint-code-builder/int-address-dw-errors#preview-the-result-of-your-function) is not enough then you should try the DataWeave Playground instead (https://dataweave.mulesoft.com/learn/). Or report the issue to the beta extension project.